# wait(n) is acting different each time I change the position of synchronized keyword

Tags: java, multithreading

Refer below code

```
     public void acquire(){
        synchronized(a){
            print("acquire()");
            try{
                //Thread.sleep(5000);
                synchronized(this){
                    wait(5000);
                }
                print("I have awoken");
                print("" + a);
            }catch(Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        print("Leaving acquire()");
    }


    public void modify(int n){
        print("Entered in modfy");
        synchronized(a){
            try{
                //Thread.sleep(5000);
                synchronized(this){
                    wait(5000);
                }
                this.a=n;
                print("new value" + a);
            }catch(Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
```

And

```
        final SynchoTest ttObj = new SynchoTest();
        Thread A = new Thread(new Runnable(){
            public void run() {
                ttObj.acquire();    
            }
        },"A");

        Thread B = new Thread(new Runnable(){
            public void run() {
                ttObj.modify(97);   
            }
        },"B");
        A.start();
        B.start();
```

As i know about wait(n), it pauses a thread until notify()/notifyAll() get called or the specified time n is over.

But...

- In above methods if I directly use wait(n) as I used Thread.sleep(n),
  I get runtime exception.
- If I synchronize both methods instead of surrounding wait(n) with
  synchronized block then I am not getting any exception but both
  threads get blocked forever.
- But if I do like I attached ie wait(n) surrounding with synchronized
  block, it is working fine.

Please tell me why? Also tell me why is it not behaving different on positioning synchronized block if I use sleep(n) instead of wait(n)?

My question is about various result of wait(n) on various position of synchronized keyword.

@Gray

> notify() or notifyAll(), and wait() must be in a synchronized block
>   for the object you are waiting on

explained me why I was getting run time exception by positioning synchronized block on various position.

Now please explain me, why

```
public void method(){
    synchronized(a){
        synchronized(this){
            wait(n);
        }
    }
}
```

is working fine. But

```
public synchronized void method(){
    synchronized(a){
        wait(n);
    }
}
```

is blocking my thread forever.

Comment: When you say threads get blocked forever, you mean you are stuck with a blank screen because none of threads have started? `thread.start()`

Comment: Have you consdiered reading what it says in the Javadoc?

Comment: @noMAD yes it is. I printed thread state. It says it is blocked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is nothing about positioning synchronized keyword. You are facing problem since you locking other object and try to wait for another. Well @Gray has already been explained it, so not repeating it.

For your another problem, regarding why both threads are getting blocked;

> Thread A: locks this                      [A: Runnable]
>
> Thread A: locks a                     [A: Runnable]
>
> Thread B: waiting for this                    [A: Runnable, B:BLOCKED]
>
> Thread A: release this (meets wait)               [A: TIMED WAITING, B:BLOCKED]
>
> Thread B: lock this                       [A: TIMED WAITING, B: Runnable]
>
> Thread B: waiting for a which is already locked by thread A   [A: TIMED WAITING, B:BLOCKED]
>
> Thread A: waiting for this which is locked by thread B        [A: BLOCKED, B:BLOCKED]

Answer (score 2):

Maybe your code is not working because you didn't call `start()` on your threads?  After you instantiate your threads you need to:

```
A.start();
B.start();
```

Also, you cannot do something like the following pattern.  You cannot synchronize on `a` and then change the object of `a`.  Well you can do it but I doubt that's what you want.  Basically the `a` would change and someone else locking on `a` would lock on another object so would be able to be in the synchronized block as well.  Very bad pattern.

```
synchronized (a) {
    ...
    // not good
    this.a = n;
}
```

Also, if you are not joining with the threads, then the main thread is going to continue on and not wait for `A` and `B` to finish.  The JVM will wait for them to finish however since they are not daemon threads.  And you have no guarantee that `A` will be called before `B` so the modify and acquire can happen in any order.

The difference between `sleep(5000)` and `wait(5000)` is that the `wait` can also be awoken by a call to `notify()` or `notifyAll()`, and `wait()` must be in a `synchronized` block for the object you are waiting on.  `synchronized` also causes a memory barrier to be crossed which synchronizes the storage between multiple threads.  It is more expensive because of that but in your case since you look to be sharing `this.a` then the memory barrier is required.

Comment: I have added 2 more lines about how i start thread. Although If i dont start thread I can not stick in this situation.

Comment: +1 for suggestion about I should not modify an object I am locking on. Your statement **...must be in a synchronized block for the object you are waiting on.** solved my problem. I just replaced `wait(n)` with `a.wait(n)`

Comment: as you suggested, we should not synchronized an object might be modified in synchronized block. Using synchronized(this) everywhere is also not a good practice. So how would I decide which object I should synchronize?

Comment: You should synchronize on a constant object (often it should be `final`).  Defining a `Object lock = new Object();` is a frequent pattern.  If you have a `Set` you want to `synchronize` then you should synchronize on it as long as you don't replace the `Set` object.

Answer (score 2):

`wait(n)` and `sleep(n)` are completely different methods for pausing the execution of code:

`wait(n)` is called on an `Object` instance and will pause execution until the `notify()`/`notifyAll()` method is called on that instance or until the timer (the parameter) expires.

`sleep(n)` is called on a `Thread` object and essentially stops the world as far as that thread is concerned.

What your question comes down to is:

- Do you want your object to act as a mutex, waiting for another piece of code to complete before continuing on it's own? Then use `wait(n)` with a corresponding `notify()`/`notifyAll()` in the other code.
- Do you want to stop execution of the whole thread for a given timeframe? Then use `Thread.sleep(n)`.

Comment: I am clear with difference between sleep(n) and wait(n). I have edited question to clarify my query.