# Where to call wait()

Tags: java, multithreading

In my java program, when I code

```
synchronized(a){
    a = 55;
    a.wait();
}
```

It gives run time exception `java.lang.IllegalMonitorStateException` on `a.wait();` statement. However `a=55` runs successfully.

But if I code as

```
synchronized(a){
    a.wait();
    a = 55;
}
```

then it runs perfectly without any exception. why so?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because `a` is pointing to a different object after reassignment, and is not being synchronized on.

In other words, there are two objects, `val1` and `val2` that are both assigned to the variable `a`.  You synchronize on `val1` but in the first example call wait on `val2`.  The monitor you use is attached to the *object*, not its variable.

You should thus avoid synchronizing by referencing a non-final variable.  This leads to your confusion.  If the field is mutable, use another lock, for example:

```
Object aMonitor = new Object();

synchronized(aMonitor) {
   a = 55;
   aMonitor.wait();
}
```

Ideally your scenario is just for learning though.  `wait()` and `notify()` are primitives and shouldn't be used unless as an exercise or for building your own concurrency library.  If it's for real code, use a higher level mechanism in [`java.util.concurrent`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/package-summary.html).

Answer (score 2):

Because you have replaced the object `a` when you do the assignment.  This is called auto-boxing.  `a = 55` actually creates a new `Integer` object so then when you call `a.wait()` on it, it is waiting on a different object that you have not synchronized on which is why you get the exception.

As I mentioned in the answer to [your other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9571982/waitn-is-acting-different-each-time-i-change-the-position-of-synchronized-keyw/9572023), you cannot assign an object inside of a `synchronized` block.   Even the following pattern is a bad idea because then you assign `a` to a different object, it means the next thread to call `synchronized` will be doing so on a different `a` so 2 threads can be in the same `synchronized` block at the same time.

```
synchronized(a){
    a.wait();
    // still a bad idea
    a = 55;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the first case, variable a (after assigned to a new integer) is not the "a" that's been locked by synchronized(a), so calling a.wait() results an exception.