# Unable to simulate use of volatile field modifier

Tags: java, multithreading

In below example

```
    private Integer a = 10;
    private Integer c = -10;
    private int b = -10;

    public void acquire(){
        synchronized(a){
            print("acquire()");
            try{                    
                b = -12;
                //Thread.sleep(5000);
                a.wait(5000);
                print("acquire : "+b);
                print("I have awoken");
            }catch(Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        print("Leaving acquire()");
    }


    public void modify(int n){
        print("Entered in modfy");
        synchronized(a){
            try{                    
                b = -15;
                //a.wait(5000);
                Thread.sleep(5000);
                print("modfy : "+b);
            }catch(Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
```

Thread A is calling acquire(), Thread B is calling modify().

Value of b changed by one thread is visible to another thread.

1. Thread A: b=-12; and waits
2. Thread B: b=-15; prints b; exit
3. Thread A: prints new value of b ie -15.

How can i simulate **need of volatile** with above example then **use of volatile** in above example.

Comment: Previous questions in this thread are: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9571982/waitn-is-acting-different-each-time-i-change-the-position-of-synchronized-keyw/9572023 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9577913/where-to-call-wait

Comment: You are not guaranteed to be hit by a car, even if you cross the street without looking both ways. There is no method that is guaranteed to fail, the rules don't work that way. (Just as there is no way to cross the street without looking that *guarantees* you'll get hit by a car.)

Comment: @Gray, not a homework. Just trying to clear all concept of multithreading in single day.

Comment: @articlestack I would suggest even with ten years multi-threaded programming experience you will still be learning. ;)

Comment: @PeterLawrey true. But at least cleared with concept up to some level. Let me answers other questions to check how much I have learnt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have an example here

http://vanillajava.blogspot.com/2012/01/demonstrating-when-volatile-is-required.html

The problems you are likely to find are;

- While `volatile` provides some memory consistency guarantees, not using volatile **doesn't** guarantee you will see a problem.
- The problem doesn't appear to happen in the Sun/Oracle/OpenJDK JVM until the code has been optimised i.e. after it has been run 10,000 times.
- There is a usually a subtle race condition involved and changing even minor things may mean you don't see a problem.

Answer (score 1):

If you simply want to simulate the need of `volatile` simply do this:

```
volatile int x = 10;
public void acquire()
{
     x = 15;   
     print("acquire()");
}

public void modify(int n)
{
     print("Entered in modfy");
     x = -15;
}

//Let threadA call acquire() and threadB call modify()Then print x and see (there should not be any race conditions)
```

If you want to make it more fun, add a few more threads and methods and try to access `x`

Comment: If its so simple perhaps you can provide a complete example. ;)

Comment: @PeterLawrey: I sense sarcasm here :). I used `volatile` while writing multi-threaded Java program with sockets. I would have a common token (`volatile int array`) which multiple threads update. I thought this might be on the same lines. If its not, please elaborate.

Comment: I suspects its not as simple to demonstrate as you suggest, but I am happy to be proven wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Accoding to "Concurrency in Practice - Book", volatile should be used only for flags kind of variables.(which are booleans). 
Volatile should be used where the new state does not depend on old state of variable ..

volatile boolean flag = true;

while(flag) {
..//do something;

}

when the flag variable can be modified by other threads, the original thread will be notified because the flag is tagged volatile. Otherwise, the loop may go forever.